# MS SQL Find the value of a previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still getting my head around joins and things like that.

Here is my problem...

We have a table with a column that contains a lot of information about a particular "nick name", which is entered when we sell the product. Unfortunately there is no way to tie records with the same nick name together except by their nick name.

One of the values in each row is a shelf number of where the product was placed when it sold.

We haven't used this information before but now we want to add a new row that also includes the shelf number the product sat on the last time it sold.

This is not a big problem for new records as I use ASP to add records and can easily do a last record update to get the value.

The problem is we want to go over 220,000 records and do the same thing and although I have written a script in ASP to do it...it is taken forever to run even though I have broken the script down to run on one days sales at a time (ASP Classic).

So I was wonder if there was an SQL equivalent on Microsoft SQL server 12.

new record | nick name    | shelf | last shelf

2152       | 'old orange' | 10    | 9

Just so you know each record does have a unique id and a date stamp.

The issue is further compounded because sometimes products are not sold during a selling period so the last record may contain a null not a number. In this instance I want to ignore this record and go to the one before that if there is one.

Thank you if you are able to help.

Malc

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what is the problem. For better answers you, probably will need to show a sample of the data and what is exactly required as an output. Create a SQLFiddle, perhaps?

Comment: It sounds from the description that you might need an insert trigger to do this. The 'last shelf' would be inserted as null from your code and the insert trigger would find the latest rows with matching nicknames, and take the shelf ID from that; if one is not found it leaves the column null.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

Changed this answer to provide the trigger and a sample update that sets the last shelf for existing data. The SQL has been modified to add this.

---

The simplest solution I can think of is to use an insert trigger. Here is a test script you can run on a non-production SQL server. I've used some code in the trigger which works with MS SQL Server version 2005 or later (the 'over' clause for partitioning). I tested it on SQL 2008 but not on any other versions or on SQLexpress.

I added in a datestamp column as that is required to know which record is the latest.

The logic in the trigger is to exclude the new records, and find the items with the latest datestamp and the highest ID. If two items for the same nickname exist for the same date, it uses the value with the highest id. It excludes any item where Shelf is null.

In the table I also added a column called 'expected' to store what I expect the LastShelf column to contain for that row. In my test they all matched.

#### Possible problems

If you do batch inserts in a single SQL statement which have multiple items with the same nickname, the LastShelf will be from the existing data, and won't pick up any of Shelf values in the inserted data. Perhaps some kind SQL expert could suggest a rewrite of my insert statement that would cure this?

Hope this helps..

```
-- Create a demo database (
use master;
go

create database [Demo_Trigger];
go

use Demo_Trigger;

-- Create the table we want to test
create table Items 
    (ID int not null identity primary key,  -- primary key
     datestamp datetime not null,           -- timestamp of record (to find last entry)
     nickname nvarchar(64) not null,        -- nickname
     shelf int null,                        -- shelf (can be null)
     lastShelf int null,                    -- last shelf
     expected int null);                    -- for testing/demo - what we expect result to be!

GO

-- Create an insert trigger 
create trigger Items_InsertSetLastShelf
on Items after Insert as
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- determine unique list of nicknames being inserted 
  update Items
  Set LastShelf = tmp.Shelf
  from Items, 
  (
    select nickname, shelf from 
    (
        select id, nickname, datestamp, shelf,
            MAX(datestamp) over (partition by nickname) maxDate, -- get latest by date
            MAX(id) over (partition by nickname) maxID           -- get highest id
        from items
        where shelf is not null -- ignore null shelf
        and nickname in (select distinct nickname from inserted) -- only search for inserted nicknames
        and items.id not in (select id from inserted) -- exclude new records
    ) tmp2
    where datestamp = maxdate and id = maxID
  ) tmp
  where Items.nickname = tmp.Nickname and items.ID IN (SELECT ID from inserted)

END;

GO


-- create some items to test functionality
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-01','aaa',1, null); -- aaa on shelf 1
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-01','aaa',2, 1); -- aaa on shelf 2 but same date as previous
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-02','bbb',2, null); -- bbb on shelf 2, no prev record
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-03','aaa',3, 2); -- aaa - should have lastShelf=2, as that was the last record, not 1 
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-04','aaa',null, 3); -- aaa again, but null shelf, lastShelf=3
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-06','aaa',4, 3); -- aaa last shelf should ignore null, still 3
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-08','bbb',1, 2); -- bbb lastShelf=2
insert items (datestamp, nickname, shelf, expected) values ('2014-01-06','aaa',5, 4); -- aaa lastShelf should be 4

-- show results
select * from Items;
```

At this point, the items are correct, so now remove the LastShelf to simulate the existing records:

```
update Items set LastShelf =null;
```

This query will set the LastShelf value for existing records: the shelf must not be null, have the same nickname and an earlier date and lower ID. For entries with the same date, the shelf from the higher ID is used. You can check the results by comparing "expected" with last shelf.

```
update Items
set lastShelf = tmp.computed
from (
select i1.ID, i1.Nickname, i1.shelf, i1.expected,
(select top 1 i3.shelf from 
    (
    select id, nickname, datestamp, shelf,
        MAX(datestamp) over (partition by nickname) maxDate, -- get latest by date
        MAX(id) over (partition by nickname) maxID           -- get highest id
    from items i2
    where i2.shelf is not null -- ignore null shelf
    and i2.nickname = i1.nickname -- same nickname
    and i2.datestamp <= i1.datestamp -- date is earlier than this record
    and i2.ID < i1.ID -- ID is lower than this record
    ) i3 where i3.maxDate = i3.datestamp and i3.ID = i3.maxID
) computed
from Items i1
) tmp where Items.ID = tmp.ID;
```

Comment: Just realised it was the *existing* records you were having a problem with, not the new inserts - so my answer doesn't help you with that. I'll see if I can knock up a query that does this for you.

Comment: Updated with new SQL query that should help. 220,000 records should not be an issued for SQL, but you might want to add SQL Indexes to the table if you have not already done so. I'd recommend one on Nickname and possibly one on DateStamp.